# Callback a function with previously unknown arguments in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, design-patterns, callback, argument-passing

I was thinking about doing a `take_timing` function that would take the timing of any function passed to it.  By **any function** it means that the arguments this callback takes is unknown by the caller. It would take too the arguments for the callback. But as it doesn't know how to call it, it would take another callback function, the caller of the callback, written by the function user. The stub would be something like this:

```
void take_timing(
    void (*callback)(),
    void (*caller(void (*callback)(),void* args_struct),
    void* args_struct
)
{
    // Start timer

    caller(callback,args_struct);

    // Stop timer, read timings, record...
}

void some_caller(void (*callback)(),void* args_struct)
{
    // Cast "callback" to function signature
    // Cast args_struct to some struct with args
    // Call the callback with correct args signature
}
```

So comes my questions:

1. Is it possible?
2. Can it use variable arguments list to make it simples? How? I am helpless on this...
3. Is there a better way of doing it? Or is it just better to do a `take_timing` for every specific case?
4. Is there a OOP Design Pattern for this for use with C++?

I myself gave up on this, but put it here out of curiosity, maybe some very useful insights.

Comment: What's the value in the extra abstraction?  Why not just take a known callback function type with a context pointer?  I don't see the value-add here, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take a functor as a template argument. Something like:

```
template<typename F>
nanoseconds take_timing(F f) {

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    f();
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    return end - start;
}

long long factorial(int i);

take_timing( [](){factorial(20);} ); // wrap call to function taking arguments in zero-argument lambda
```

Comment: Hmm, that was really great, worked perfectly and is not mind boggling, very simple to read, understand and use. Let's just wait and see if there is a plain-C way of doing it too.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `varargs` support, which does exist in ANSI C.  A gazillion or so google hits will result if you search for it.  Here's one at random: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html

Comment: Alright, but is there a way to pass `varargs` to another function? In our case, `take_timing` gets a `va_list`. But how would it call `caller` and pass the arguments from `va_list` to it?

Comment: If the function being called can also take a va_list of arguments, then yes.  IE, if the parent function is foo(va_list args) then it can certainly easily call bar(va_list args), passing the same set of arguments (or mucking with it first).

Comment: I think that it makes it a valid solution then, albeit a mind boggling one. In fact, that's what I had in mind in the first time, but I wasn't sure that passing the macro-handled `va_list` was valid. Also, when started coding, I saw it was no good design on usability, not at least for me.

Comment: It's definitely one of those cases where the C++ solution will likely look cleaner than the C one.  You may want to pick and choose depending...

Comment: You cannot simply pass on the `varargs` as easily like that in all situations. C99 defines [va_copy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_copy). C89 does not, but can be redefined if it doesn't exist like this: `#define va_copy(dest,src) memcpy(&dest, &src, sizeof (va_list))`

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle this is to take a boost::bind function object as your parameter:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/bind/bind.html

You could hide the fact that closures are involved with macros.

Comment: Nice to know about this too. But I think it might get "deprecated" nowadays with C++11 standard.